# When is PHFetchResultChangeDetails's "hasMoves" equal to YES?

Tags: ios, photokit

I'm writing my subclasses of `PHChange` along with `PHFetchResultChangeDetails`.
I understand fields like `insertedIndexes`, `insertedObjects`, `fetchResultBeforeChanges`, `fetchResultAfterChanges` etc.

What I can't understand is a field `hasMoves`. Documentation says that it's `"A Boolean value that indicates whether objects have been rearranged in the fetch result"`.

So my questions are: 
1. What should the user do to reproduce the case when `hasMoves = YES` ? 
2. If `hasMoves = YES` can the moves be calculated out of `insertedIndexes`\ `changedIndexes` \ `removedIndexes`, or don't I have access to the information about moves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it **is** possible to rearrange photos in the custom albums (but not the standard ones like `CameraRoll`, `Favorites` etc):

*Open the album you want to organize. Hold your finger gently on the photo you want to move, then drag it to a different position. Release your finger to drop it into the new position.*

Programmatically, `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest` can be used:

```
- (void)replaceAssetsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes 
                withAssets:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)assets;
```