# When is PHFetchResultChangeDetails's "hasIncrementalChanges" equal to NO?

Tags: ios, photosframework, phphotolibrary

This question is similar to this one: [When is PHFetchResultChangeDetails's "hasMoves" equal to YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541322/when-is-phfetchresultchangedetailss-hasmoves-equal-to-yes)

What should the user do in order to force `PHPhotoLibrary` to send `PHChange` where `hasIncrementalChanges` is `NO`?

Comment: This seems to get triggered whenever you take a new photo in app while you have your photo permission settings set to "selected photos only". Although I suspect it's a bug.